# How to get the time in Ng-Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I was wondering is there a straight forward way to get the time in the ng-bootstrap datepicker? So far my code is:

```
 <input class="form-input" type="text" id="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" [navigation]="navigation"
    formControlName="date" (click)="d.toggle()"><i class="form-icon icon icon-calendar calendar-icon" (click)="d.toggle()"></i><h6 class="text-gray mt-2">xxxxx</h6>
```

**ts file:**

```
model: NgbDateStruct;
date: {year: number, month: number};
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can add a custom date adapter as given in the [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter)

Comment: But that is for a date only?? do you have code example?

Comment: Sorry I have the same code which came with ng-bootstrap custom date picker example. If you like you can select 'angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker' and it has hour and minute views which allows the user to select the hour/minute of the day, on the selected day [link](https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/) . Anyway please share if you find a solution in ng-datepicker.

Comment: There is a feature-type [issue](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2086) on **ng-bootstrap**'s repo about this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Timepicker of ngx-bootstrap. If you are really in need to implement time and date in same pop-up, then try the link below.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am not too late, but since you are already using Ng Bootstrap, you might as well use the [TimePicker module](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples) which is part of Ng Bootstrap. This way, you can simply import it together with the DatePicker module.

```
import { NgbDatepickerModule, NgbTimepickerModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

I have previously made a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdxxwm?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) as someone else asked a similar question. Feel free to check it out and see how it works!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular

### How to Use

1. Install with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com):`npm install ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular --save`
2. Add NgBootstrapDateTimeAngularModule to your **@NgModule** like example below

   ```js
   import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
   import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

   import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
   import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
   import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

   import { NgBootstrapDateTimeAngularModule } from "ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular";

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [AppComponent],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       NgBootstrapDateTimeAngularModule,
       CommonModule
     ],
     providers: [],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
   export class AppModule {}
   ```
3. Add your input into **form** like example below

   ```html
   <form>
     <div [formGroup]="formGroup">
       <ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular
         inputDatetimeFormat="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"
         formControlName="activeEndDate"
         name="activeEndDate"
       ></ng-bootstrap-datetime-angular>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```
4. Connect to your **component**

   ```js
   import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
   import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

   @Component({
     selector: "app-root",
     templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
     styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
   })
   export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
     title = "Date";
     formGroup: FormGroup;

     ngOnInit() {
       this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
         activeEndDate: new FormControl(null, {
           validators: [Validators.required]
         })
       });
     }
   }
   ```